# How to see the native implementation of predefined rules in Bazel

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules

I am learning currently Bazel and after going through a few tutorials I feel like I have some basic working knowledge with it. Now I would like to dig slightly deeper and see how some of the rules I am using, like `android_binary`, `android_sdk_repository`, etc, are internally defined.

So I headed to [rules_android](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/tree/master/android) on Github, and checked this one for example: https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/blob/master/android/android_sdk_repository.bzl, but as it can be seen from above, the rule definition delegates the implementation further to some `native` component. I checked out the source code, but I could not find anywhere where `native` is defined.

So what I am looking for is:

- Some guidance on how to navigate the Bazel repo
- And, specifically for the above example, where can I find the rule definition for `native.android_sdk_repository`?

Appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native rules are defined in two places:

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/tree/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules

(the reason for `lib/rules` vs `lib/bazel/rules` is that the code under `lib/rules` is shared between Bazel and Google's internal version, while the code under `lib/bazel/rules` is Bazel only)

The Android rules specifically are being re-written into Starlark, the pre-release code is in another branch:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android/tree/pre-alpha

and NDK integration into this repo:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_android_ndk

`android_sdk_repository` specifically is here:
https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/android/AndroidSdkRepositoryFunction.java

You may find it easier to explore the codebase using Bazel's CodeSearch site, because it has cross-references:

https://cs.opensource.google/bazel/bazel/+/master:src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/rules/;bpv=0;bpt=0

Answer (score 1):

`native` is the magic name to access the legacy rules, which are largely defined in Bazel's Java source. I find the definitions by cloning the Bazel sources and running `git grep '"android_ndk_repository"'`. In this case, that turns up [src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/android/AndroidNdkRepositoryRule.java](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/9ff90410feb7c4c6b9a80d414c25aa93968d62ad/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/rules/android/AndroidNdkRepositoryRule.java), which is where it's defined.

In my experience, the majority of the native rules are fairly straightforwards to understand coming from Starlark, because they mostly do the same things. There's a lot more legacy features that are not publicly documented than you'll find in Starlark code, but you're probably not using most of those.